# Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK and filtering - how to construct a call to filter on CreatedDateItem?

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` and I am trying to proof out the ability to filter `DriveItems` on the `CreatedDateTime`.

I am aware that if I construct a call like:

`await graphServiceClient.Drives["user@user.onmicrosoft.com"].Root.Request().GetAsync();`

Will return all the metadata, however, I wanted to know if there was a way to construct a call where it would filter on the `CreatedDateTime` within a single call, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply Select, Filter, etc. query options to your request as long as the underlying Graph API method supports it. It is a bit hidden but this is [documented in the wiki](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/docs/overview.md).

```
await graphServiceClient.Drives["user@user.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .Root
    .Request()
    .Filter(...)
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it a bit to search on before the request is made. 

`await graphServiceClient.Drives["user@user.onmicrosoft.com"].Search(searchQuery).Request().GetAsync();`